# Strictly convex on the set of positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need some assistance in solving this;

Let $ A, B \in M_n$ be positive definite and let $\alpha \in (0,1)$. I need to show that $\alpha A^{-1} + (1-\alpha)B^{-1} \geq ((\alpha A+(1-\alpha)B)^{-1}$ with equality iff A=B. Thus the function $ f(t)=t^{-1}$ is strictly convex on the set of positive definite matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By $\mathbf{X} \geq \mathbf{Y}$ do you mean $\mathbf{X}\succeq\mathbf{Y}$, which implies $\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{Y}$ is positive definite ? If so, then following post answers your question, [Is inverse matrix convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454699/is-inverse-matrix-convex)

Comment: Note that the accepted answer in that post is said to have a mistake.

Comment: I think the second answer by @achillehui is correct.