# Semidefinite programming formulation for a simple minimization

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

I am trying to formulate following problem (with some constraint) as a semidefinite programming problem (SDP),

\begin{equation}
\text{minimize } ~~ -a^T B^{-1} a
\end{equation}

where $B$ is a positive definite matrix. I used auxiliary variable and Schur complement and tried to formulate it as following :

\begin{eqnarray}
\text{minimize }~~ t \\ 
\text{s.t.} ~~~t \geq -a^T B^{-1} a
\end{eqnarray}

then tried to to reformulate the constraint as a Linear Matrix inequality (LMI) using Schur complement, but I got stuck to following:

\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
 t &  a'  \\
  a & -B^{-1} 
\end{array}\right] \overset{\Large\text{??}}\geq  0
\end{align*}

but the LMI is not positive definite because $-B^{-1}$ is not positive definite.

Is there another way /scape that I can formulate the original problem as SDP?

Comment: I suggest to double check the original problem. It's a convex relaxation of an Np-hard combinatorial problem?

Comment: no it's not , actually it is Mean Square Error minimization of an LMMSE estimator as var[unknown] - $a'B^{-1}a$, so I wanted to minimize it

Comment: i know, that is the problem

Comment: This is equal to $\text{maximize} a^T B^{-1} a$. Since $B$ is positive semidefinite, $B^{-1}$ is psd.  So it's maximum is infinity. Because it's a quadratic form.

Comment: I know :) , that's why I have mentioned with some constraints , if there is no constraint you are right , but I have some constraint on that

Comment: you know, you miss something. Schur complement is for semidefinite lower bound . But you want upper bound which is determined by your constraints , not mentioned here and not by semidefinite constraint.

Comment: that is the original problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445731/maximizing-a-convex-function-with-special-structure

Comment: It's not convex, so it cannot be cast as an SDP. End of story, I'm afraid.

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of your other problem---granted, you've simplified it somewhat, but it's still a duplicate. That's not good form.