# Product of the differences of two pd matrices and their respective inverses is pd

Tags: matrices, inequality, convex-optimization, positive-definite

Given two $\textbf{positive definite (pd), Hermitian}$ matrices X and Y, I am trying to determine whether $(X-Y)(Y^{-1}-X^{-1})$ will always be pd as well, and how to prove this.

This formulation appears when trying to prove that the inverse function is convex on pd matrices: [Is inverse matrix convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454699/is-inverse-matrix-convex).

It was trying to prove that if $(X-Y)\succ 0$, then $(Y^{-1}-X^{-1})\prec 0$ and vice versa, and subsequently $(X-Y)(Y^{-1}-X^{-1})\succ 0$ always. However I wasn't able to prove either of these two steps - nor disprove either of them.

Comment: What "pd" does mean?

Comment: positive definite, I assume.

Comment: This product isn't symmetric. Presumably $X$ and $Y$ are, since _usually_ that is assumed when discussing positive definiteness. Can you provide more context, please? Where did this come from, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Updated the description to better define the problem

Comment: I'd still like you to define exactly what you mean with regards to the product---which is not Hermitian. Yes, I know positive definiteness is defined even for nonsymmetric matrices, but I think it will be helpful for you to establish your definition of positive definiteness in the non-symmetric case.

Comment: This is readily refuted a number of ways. First of all, if X=Y, then the quantity is zero, as Luca points out below. But you can also try a variety of randomly generated matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Edited after After Michael's comment]** In the general case, the OP's claim is not verified. For example if
$$
X =
\begin{bmatrix}
29& 11& 19\\
11& 10& 12\\
19& 12& 19
\end{bmatrix}
, \quad
Y =
\begin{bmatrix}
14& 16& 17\\
16& 21& 22\\
17& 22& 29
\end{bmatrix}
, \quad
w =
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
we have that
$$w^T(X-Y)(Y^{-1}-X^{-1})\,w = -21002/11025.$$

The claim is verified, instead, in the special case that $X$ and $Y$ are such that $XY^{-1}$ is symmetric but one needs to relax the claim from positive definite to positive semi-definite. In fact, if $X=Y=I$, the results is the matrix of all zeros.

We could rewrite $(X-Y)(Y^{-1}-X^{-1})$ as $XY^{-1}+YX^{-1}-2I$. Then, we observe that $XY^{-1} = (YX^{-1})^{-1}$, which implies that the two must have the same eigenvectors with reciprocal eigenvalues. Therefore, the eignevalues of $XY^{-1}+YX^{-1}$ will be $\lambda_i + 1/\lambda_i$, where $\lambda_i$ is the $i$-th eigenvalue of $XY^{-1}$. We observe that $x + 1/x \ge 2\; \forall x>0$, which implies that all eigenvalues of $XY^{-1}+YX^{-1}$ are at least 2. If $XY^{-1}$ is symmetric, this implies that $XY^{-1}+YX^{-1}-2I$ is at least positive semi-definite.

Comment: Unfortunately, $(X-Y)(Y^{-1}-X^{-1})$ is not necessarily symmetric. The relationship between nonnegative eigenvalues and positive semidefiniteness applies *only* to symmetric matrices. A nonsymmetric matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite if and only if the eigenvalues of $A+A^T$ are nonnegative.

Comment: Thanks Michael for pointing this out. I have amended the answer and provided a counter example for the case when $XY^{-1}$ is not symmetric.

Comment: Are you sure X and Y are psd?

Comment: @MichaelGrant, you mean $X$ and $Y$ in my counter example? They were built as products of matrices with their transposes, e.g. $X=A^T A$ with $A=[[4, 0, 1],[2, 1, 3],[3, 3, 3]]$.

Comment: Sounds good. They didn't look PD but my intuition isn't perfect!