# Can matrix inequality induces matrix norm inequality for positive semidefinite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-matrix-inequality

**I am wondering whether matrix inequality induces matrix norm inequality for positive semidefinite matrix.**

For example, considering two positive semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$, when $A \succeq B$, does it imply
$||A||\geq ||B||$($||\cdot||$ is any matrix norm)?

I think perhaps it is true for 2-norm. Since $A \succeq B$ implies $\lambda_k(A)> \lambda_k(B),\  \text{for}\  k=1,2...n$, where $\lambda_k$ is the k-largest eigenvalues.
So, $\lambda_\max(A)> \lambda_\max(B)$.

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\|A\|_{2} &= \sqrt{\lambda_{\max }\left(A^{*} A\right)} \\
&= \sqrt{\lambda_{\max }\left(A^{T} A\right)} \\
&= \sqrt{\lambda^2_{\max }\left(A\right)} \\
&\geq \sqrt{\lambda^2_{\max }\left(B\right)} \\
&= \sqrt{\lambda_{\max }\left(B^{T} B\right)} \\
&= \|B\|_{2}.
\end{align*}

So, $A \succeq B \rightarrow \|A\|_{2}\geq ||B||_2$.

May I ask whether this reduction is correct? and does this hold for any other matrix norm?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe that if $\|\cdot\|$ is any unitarily invariant norm, then $A \succeq B$ implies that $\|A\| \geq \|B\|$. At least, this implication definitely holds for the spectral, Frobenius, and nuclear norms

Comment: And yes, the steps you have taken are correct.

Comment: It also works for the entrywise infinity norm. (!) By Cauchy-Schwarz, the largest-modulus entry of A and B is on the diagonal, and the diagonals of A, B, and B-A are nonnegative.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374500/monotone-matrix-norms

Comment: Thanks so much for your helps!